# Java error while using replaceAll("+-", "-")

Tags: java, patternsyntaxexception

I'm trying to use `String.replaceAll` but I'm getting an error:

Here is my code:

```
public static String signSimplify (String str) {
    String strr = str.replaceAll("--", "+");
    String strr2 = strr.replaceAll("-+", "-");
    String strr3 = strr2.replaceAll("+-", "-");
    return strr3;
}
```

And, when executed, I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0
+-
^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.replaceAll(Unknown Source)
    at fr.genius.main.Main.signSimplify(Main.java:108)
    at fr.genius.main.Main.calcTrinome(Main.java:88)
    at fr.genius.main.Main.main(Main.java:69)`
```

I don't understand why I can't use a replaceAll("+-", "-") but I can when + and - are inversed.

Comment: did you try to read the documentation of the `replaceAll` method?

Comment: It's a regex. `+` is a metachar for the regex, and REQUIRES something "Before" it for it to work. `-+` works, because the `+` is modifying the `-`, but `+-` DOESN'T, because there's nothing before `+` to be modified.

Comment: If you're going to use StackOverflow to ask questions that you could easily use Google to find the answer for, then at least select an answer below as the correct answer. Tom N's answer is the best answer, so if you can't decide, then select his answer.

Comment: I've searched on google for half an hour before getting here (maybe that i have searched the wrong keywords), and sorry I didn't knew that I had an answer to choose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want or need regular expressions, just use `replace()` instead of `replaceAll()` and it will work like you expected.

Comment: Ok, but it will replace all +- ? Or juste one ? thank you for the tip !

Comment: It will do a normal replacement of one string with another. If you were looking to replace both `+` and `-`, then you'll need to fix your regexp in one of several possible ways. Although it looks like you *don't* need a regexp.

Comment: @SEVENTH Yes, it will replace all instances.

Comment: Ok, I will use this instead, thank you very much to both of you :)

Answer (score 1):

replaceAll in Java treats the text to replace as a Regular Expression. You'll need to escape the +.

```
str.replaceAll("\\+-", "-")
```

Comment: Ok , i've already seen that for html or php but I had forgot how to use it, thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Use the replacement in below technique:

```
String url="abc+-abc";
System.out.println(url.replaceAll("\\+-", "-"));
```

Comment: I'm not a professional yet for sure, sorry if the question sounded nooby, thank you :)

Comment: You don't need to escape the `-` character.